# Async-safe mass delete of children with Batch

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, delete, bulk-delete

How to write in Apex a mass deletion (over 10 000 records, even up to 150 000) of related records that can be safely called from async context, like Batch?

I have two custom objects, lets call them `Source__c` (Parent) and `Payment__c` (Child). They are connected using Lookup relation. Upon deletion of a `Source__c` records, I need to delete all related Payments. For now, I'm using simple Batch that is executed from a before delete trigger. In the future, there might be a batch that will delete a `Source` record, and it should delete the `Payments` as well, but batch cannot be executed from another batch besides chaining in `finish()`. How to approach this safely, either by chaining the deletion somehow or making clear, async-safe exception to prevent such batch from running?

My code currently, part of trigger handler:

```
public with sharing class SourceTH extends TriggerHandler.DelegateBase {


    public override void prepareBefore() {
        if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            deleteRelatedPayments(Trigger.oldMap.keySet());
        }
    }

    private static void deleteRelatedPayments(Set<String> sourceIds) {
        if (!System.isFuture() && !System.isBatch()) {
            DeletePaymentsOnSourceBatch.runBatch(sourceIds);
        }
        else {
            // How to make mass delete safely from async context?
        }
    }
}
```

Batch class to delete:

```
public with sharing class DeletePaymentsOnSourceBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    private final Set<String> sourceIds = new Set<String>();

    public static void runBatch(Set<String> sourceIds){
        Database.executeBatch(new DeletePaymentsOnSourceBatch(sourceIds), 100);
    }


    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Id
                FROM Payment__c
                WHERE Source__c IN :this.sourceIds
        ]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
        delete scope;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}


}
```

Comment: in a similar situation, I used chained batchables; deleting from the bottom up

Comment: Why not use platform events to make it async, and from your platform event, call your batch deletion.